# How can I use .count() on a pandas dataframe given a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried both of these:

```
    df["Buys"] = df.groupby(['symbol','month','counterparty','side'])[df[df['side']=='Buy']].count()
    df["Sells"] = df.groupby(['symbol','month','counterparty','side'])[df['side']=='Sell'].count()
```

But for the first I get the error "DataFrame is not hashable" and for the second "True is not a key".  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I half figured it out. I did

```
dfBuys = df.groupby(['symbol','month'])['side'].apply(lambda x: (x=='Buy').sum()).reset_index(name='count')
df["Buys"] = dfBuys["count"]
```

dfBuys["count"] is exactly what I'm looking for, but for whatever reason sometimes df["Buys"] doesn't populate, but for the most part it works.